# How we can read 4 Bytes with microcontroller and SPI communication

Tags: c++, microcontroller, atmel

I want to transfer and get data from my microcontroller to my SPI memory chip with 4 Bytes (256 octets), i developped my code below, i want to write some Bytes then read it from Read function, but i get different value in 4 Bytes ( exemple i send 0x10011111 i get A100A1F0)

In the datasheet of the Memory chip, there are no information about Page transfer (256 bits) and the transfer of data is always in double Byte ( 1 word = 16 bits)

**this is my Code for write 4 Bytes:**

```
  void ecrire4OctetsFRAM(uint32_t const addressRegister, uint32_t const fourBytes, uint8_t const slaAddress)
{
    if (fourBytes != lire4OctetsFRAM(addressRegister, slaAddress))
    {
        if(addressRegister%4)
        {
            ecrire1OctetFRAM(addressRegister+3,(uint32_t) (fourBytes>> 24),FRAM);
            ecrire1OctetFRAM(addressRegister+2,(uint32_t) (fourBytes>> 16),FRAM);
            ecrire1OctetFRAM(addressRegister+1,(uint32_t) (fourBytes>> 8),FRAM);
            ecrire1OctetFRAM(addressRegister,  (uint32_t) (fourBytes)    ,FRAM);




        }
        else
        {
            uint8_t tries(0);
            do 
            {
                error = 0;
                positionnerPointeur(addressRegister, slaAddress);
                if (error) continue;
                transfer((uint8_t) (fourBytes));
                if (error) continue;
                transfer((uint8_t) (fourBytes>> 8));
                if (error) continue;
                transfer((uint8_t) (fourBytes>>16));
                if (error) continue;
                transfer((uint8_t) (fourBytes>>24));
                release();
            } while (error && ++tries < MAX_TRIES);
            error = (tries >= MAX_TRIES)? TW_MAX_TRIES: error;
        }
    }
}
```

**and this is for read**

```
uint32_t    lire4OctetsFRAM  (uint32_t const addressregister, uint8_t const slaveadress ){


uint32_t fourBytes(0);
uint8_t tries(0);
//**
do
    {   error = 0;
    positionnerPointeur(addressregister, slaveadress);
    select();
    transfer(READ);

    fourBytes = transfer((uint32_t) ((addressregister >>  24) & 0xFFFF));
    fourBytes += transfer((uint32_t) ((addressregister >> 16) & 0xFF));
    fourBytes += transfer((uint32_t) ((addressregister >>   8) & 0xFF));

    fourBytes +=transfer((uint32_t) ( addressregister & 0xFF));
    transfer(0);
    fourBytes = SPDR; 
    fourBytes += (fourBytes << 24) ;
    fourBytes += (fourBytes << 16);
    fourBytes = (fourBytes <<  8);
transfer(0);
    fourBytes += SPDR; 
    release();
}
while (error && ++tries < MAX_TRIES);
error = (tries >= MAX_TRIES)? TW_MAX_TRIES: error;
return fourBytes ; 
}
```

Positionnerpointeur is a function to point a bit address ( pointer).

Comment: Why are you assigning to `fourBytes` so many times? Why do you use `+=` in most assignments? Have you tried to debug the code, or at least "print out" the value of `fourBytes` after every step to see when and where it gets the wrong value (I recommend you print it out as hexadecimal).

Comment: You say "4 Bytes (256 octets)".  Which do you mean?  There are *very* few systems nowadays where a byte is not the same as an octet (and I know of none with a 64 octet byte - that is *huge*).

Comment: in the debugger, i couldn't see the fourbytes value and i don't know why, i do use += because i transfer shifted data

Comment: @MartinBonner i mean that i would transfer 256 bits ( 4 Bytes), ( 1 byte = 1 word = 16 bits according to my datasheet)

Comment: Regarding `+=` and shifting. Lets say that `fourBytes` is assigned the value `0x0001` and you do `fourBytes += fourBytes << 8`, then the result is `0x0101`. Is that really the correct result according to you?

Comment: If you say that one byte is 16 bits, the four bytes would be 4*16 bits, which 64 bits. And usually a byte and a word is not the same. Are you sure the datasheets doesn't say that one word is two bytes?

Comment: Yes i'm sure that datasheet says that 1 word = 16 bits

Comment: @D.G Please [edit] your question to be coherent.  If one word is 16 bits, then four of them is 64 bits (and not 256 bits).  Further an octet is not a single bit, but 8 bits (hence the name).  For most usages an octet and a byte are the same thing (except when you are digging into the depths of the C and C++ standards).  You *appear* to be trying to transfer 4 bytes, which is two words or 32 bits.

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: ok, maybe  i could'nt say it in English because i speak Frensh, i want to transfer 256 bits simultaneously for one time

Comment: my question is how can i shift the data to be able to transfer 256 bits

Comment: What flash chip are you using? Your code says FRAM, not flash.

Comment: yes it's FRAM and this is the datasheet http://www.fujitsu.com/us/Images/MB97R803A-DS411-00003-1v0-E.pdf

Comment: You need to read that datasheet.  It tells you how to communicate with the chip bit by bit.